# Find most similar array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
a=[168, 76, 62, 86]

b=[168, 80, 65, 90]
```

My input

```
[166.5, 75.5, 62, 86]
```

Now I want to get array "a" as my "result" because it is more similar to "a" than it is to "b".

How can I do that?

Comment: Define similar? did you try to search the web for an answer before?

Comment: You have to be more specific. If my a,b arrays are `[1, 2, 1, 2]` and `[3, 1, 1, 1]`  and my input is `[1, 1, 1, 1]` then which one should the algorithm choose? Based on what rules?

Comment: what is "the most similar" to you? how do you weight a single strong outlier over many close fits? like is `[166.5, 75.5, 62, 40]` closer to your input than `[168, 76, 62, 86]`? how "close" has this one outlier have to come to make `[166.5, 75.5, 62, x]` "more similar" to the input than `[168, 76, 62, 86]`? The question basically is, how do YOU determine distance? a few possibilities would be *sum of the deltas* to the input, *sum delta²*, *smallest max(delta)*, and a few more. Without any info about the meaning of these numbers we can't even recommend a proper method.

Comment: I need this to calculate dress sizes. It is very unlikely that there is a lot of fluctuation, therefore each number in the input will only be a bit higher or smaller.

Comment: @Yanic, OK, but that doesn't change the question. Even if the differences are small, how do you tell wich one is the better match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could collect the absolute deltas and choose the one with the smaller error.

```js
var array1 = [168, 76, 62, 86],
    array2 = [168, 80, 65, 90],
    input = [166.5, 75.5, 62, 86],
    error = [array1, array2].map(function (a) {
        return input.reduce(function (r, b, i) {
            return r + Math.abs(a[i] -b);
        }, 0);
    });
  
console.log(error); // [2, 13] take the first one with smaller error.
```

Comment: I like the use of reduce, makes my answer so boring ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you've got two number arrays

x = [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>]

y = [y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, ..., y<sub>n</sub>]

The difference (i.e inverse similarity) between them is calculated by passing them through some error function *E* let's say

*E = Σ (x<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*

it's the same as calculating:

*(x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + ... + (x<sub>n</sub> - y<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*

*= Σx<sup>2</sup> + Σy<sup>2</sup> - Σ(2x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>)*

*= Σx<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + Σy<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2Σx<sub>i</sub>Σy<sub>i</sub>*

which means we can now use just the built-in Javascript methods `.map()` and `.reduce()`.

```
const toSquare(ar) = ar.map( v => v*v )
const sum(ar) = ar.reduce( (acc, v) => acc + v )

function error(ar1, ar2) {
  return sum(toSquare(ar1)) + sum(toSquare(ar2)) + 2*sum(ar1)*sum(ar2)
}
```

---

Much simpler:

you can also use [underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash's](https://lodash.com/) `.zip` function:

```
function error(ar1, ar2) {
    return _.zip([ar1, ar2]).map( pair => Math.pow(p[0]-p[1], 2) ).reduce( (acc, v) => acc + v )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a manual function to do that.
There is no built in way to do so.

```
function closest( inputArray, controlArrays) {

    var margins;
    for(var i=0, iMax=controlArrays.length; i < iMax; i++ ){
        margins[i] = 0;
        for(var j=0, jMax=inputArray.length; j < jMax; j++) {
            //get the difference between the numbers and add it for the margins for that control array
            margins[i] += Math.abs(inputArray[j]-controlArrays[j][i]);
        }
    }
    //find smallest margin
    var index = 0;
    var value = margins[0];
    for (var m = 1, mMax = temp.length; m < mMax; m++) {
        if (temp[m] < value) {
            value = temp[m];
            index = m;
        }
    }
    //return the smalles margin;
    return controlArrays[index];
}
```